Unable to do getenv in typescript
let curr_display: string = env.get('DISPLAY_ID') ;
this code gives an error
Type 'IOptionalVariable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
Does this mean there is no guarantee that this variable may not exist, and how to solve this ?
env.get is coming from a module env-var

What is env.get? What system/library are you using for handling env variables?

Coming from a module env-var

Ok well reading its documentation might help. env.get('DISPLAY_ID').required().asString()

env.get() does not return a string, exactly as the message says.

it worked, thanks guys.
